# Unordered list css style is in Flash

Tags: css, flash, actionscript-3

I've run into a bug and I'm hoping there is a fix, but not holding my breath with the limited capabilities of CSS in Flash.

I have an unordered list, of which some list items contain links. Here is an example of the html below.

```
<ul>
  <li>one point</li>
  <li>two <a href='#'>point</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>three point</a></li>
</ul>
```

The problem is that I have used CSS to style the anchor links to be a different color, which works fine except that it changes the bullet color too. Oddly it only does this on list items that contain links.

I've quickly put together a demo to show my problem here [link text](http://scmwebdev.com/badul/bad_ul.html)

The CSS is really simple and only contains 2 lines.

```
ul, li { color: #FFFFFF; }
a { color: #BEB085; }
```

The first being a poor attempt to fix.

If anyone has any thoughts it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
    <div class= "hrf"> two <a href='#'>point</a></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Css:

```
.hrf a{
    color:#BEBO;
}
```

Try this

Comment: Just did a quick test and it doesn't appear to work. In fact a little more testing showed that you can't reference child items. For example  li { color: #2222ee; } will work but ul li { color: #2222ee; } won't.